# Ошибка при запуске Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox

Моя ОС Win7, виртуалка работала отлично от установки год назад до сегодняшнего дня.

Сегодня при входе получил сообщение об выходе новой стабильной версии VirtualBox, пропустил его и запустил свой убунту дистрибутив.
При загрузке системы на виртуалке получил критическую ошибку guru meditation.

Перезагрузил комп, проверил настройки виртуализации в биосе и запустил все по новой: на этот раз загрузка прошла успешно, но ошибку я получил позже при обновлении самой убунты внутри виртуалки.
Подумал что это косяк обновления виртуалки или линукса или еще чего.

Снес виртуалку, снес всю инфу о прошлой убунте, переустановил заново виртуалку самой свежей версии и скачал самую свежую убунту.
На этот раз получил критическую ошибку guru meditation при установке убунты на виртуалку, вплоть до синего экрана смерти.

Снес все еще раз и установил старую виртуалку и старую версию убунты.

При загрузке виртуалки начал получать ошибку следующего вида:

```
Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины Ubuntu.
The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
Код ошибки: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент: ConsoleWrap
Интерфейс: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Попробовал установить более легковесную xubuntu (подумал что вдруг комп не тянет просто).
Та же самая петрушка: то текст ошибки выше, то ошибка гуру.

Разрядность системы не нарушаю, места на диске достаточно, виртуалка в биосе включена, разные галки в настройках виртуалки выставлял по-разному как писали на форумах, в "программах и компонентах" искал VT-x чтоб убрать галку(его там просто нет у меня)

Comment: `VT-x is disabled in the BIOS` - смотрите в BIOS.

Comment: Я проверил настройки биоса, сначала выключил виртуализацию, потом включил. Все равно не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте спросить на форуме VirtualBox, там больше шансов, что помогут. Возможно что несовместимость чего-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переустановкой драйверов процессора.