# Virtualbox не видит виртуализацию

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox, bios

Моя ОС Win7, виртуалка работала отлично от установки год назад до сегодняшнего дня.
Не так давно удалил другую виртуалку Scummvm. Сегодня при входе получил сообщение об выходе новой стабильной версии VirtualBox, пропустил его и запустил свой убунту дистрибутив. При загрузке системы на виртуалке получил критическую ошибку guru meditation. Перезагрузил комп, проверил настройки виртуализации в биосе и запустил все по новой: на этот раз загрузка прошла успешно, но ошибку я получил позже при обновлении самой убунты внутри виртуалки. Подумал что это косяк обновления виртуалки или линукса или еще чего. Снес виртуалку, снес всю инфу о прошлой убунте, переустановил заново виртуалку самой свежей версии и скачал самую свежую убунту. На этот раз получил критическую ошибку guru meditation при установке убунты на виртуалку, вплоть до синего экрана смерти. Снес все еще раз и установил старую виртуалку и старую версию убунты. При загрузке виртуалки начал получать ошибку следующего вида:

```
Не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины Xubuntu.

The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Код ошибки: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Компонент: ConsoleWrap Интерфейс: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Попробовал установить более легковесную xubuntu (подумал что вдруг комп не тянет просто). Та же самая петрушка: то текст ошибки выше, то ошибка гуру.

Разрядность системы не нарушаю, места на диске достаточно, **виртуалка в биосе включена 100%**, разные галки в настройках виртуалки выставлял по-разному как писали на форумах, в "программах и компонентах" искал VT-x чтоб убрать галку(его там просто нет у меня)

Команду `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` выполнял, компьютер перезагружал.

Модель ноута: asus N53S. Проц: intel i5-2410m. Мать: N53S

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1394281/178576) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1394623/178576)

Comment: Да, на случай если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой. Для простоты поиска.